# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log(1 - \frac{x}{n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was curious whether there is a direct way to determine
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log\left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)
$$
for $x\in [0,1)$. Sampling for certain $x$ suggests that this series converges. Furthermore, according to Wolfram Alpha, and then some manipulations with the zeta function, we are able to obtain
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{k} \log\left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right) = \log\left(\frac{\Gamma(k+1-x)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(1-x)}\right),
$$
but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: For bounded real $x< 1$ and large $n$, $$
\log \left( {1 - \frac{x}{n}} \right) =  - \frac{x}{n} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right)
$$ showing that it diverges unless $x=0$.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you and @SolubleFish for the answer. I misread the results from earlier. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: You should check your sampling, following the answer not matching your heuristics. I've suffered a lot from false deduction from simulations, to the extent that I've had to force myself to use pen and paper for hours even before programming the simulation! While that cannot be discussed in this thread, it shows that this might be a good lesson going forward.

Comment: Linearizing the log-Gamma function, $\ln\frac{\Gamma(k+1-x)}{\Gamma(k+1)}\approx -x\ln k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $x$ fixed and as $n\to +\infty$, we have :
$$\log\left(1-\frac xn\right) \sim -\frac xn$$
Since the RHS has constant sign and its series diverges, so does the series of the LHS (except for $x =0$).

Answer (score 1):

$$S_k=\sum_{n=1}^{k} \log\left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)=\log \Bigg[\prod_{n=1}^{k} \left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)\Bigg]=\log \left(\frac{(1-x)_k}{k!}\right)=\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (k-x+1)}{\Gamma (k+1) \Gamma (1-x)}\right)$$ Using Stirling approximation twice
$$S_k=-\log (\Gamma (1-x))-x \color{red}{\log (k)}+\frac{(x-1) x}{2 k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$$